# Buggy UICollectionView when loading cached image from parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I have some images on parse. (5 objects each has a PFFile an image of about 800x800 400Kb each).
When i first run the application on my device (iphone 5S), the images load, and all is OK.
When i scroll down to load all. Then i scoll up again and the images loaded earlier (once at least and cached by parse)
the UICollectionView flickers a little (not too slow but noticeable, like the UI is trying to keep up with the drag).
I there anything i am missing ?

*EDIT 1 :
Any help or refinement of my code is much appreciated

**Calling the CustomCell:**

```
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellImage";
cellTypeImage1 *cell = (cellTypeImage1 *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell configureWithObject:[self.collectionView objectAtIndex:indexPath]];
return cell;
```

**Inside the custom cell**

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {


        self.fullResImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.fullResImage.frame = CGRectZero;
        [self addSubview:self.fullResImage];

    }
    self.backgroundColor = [color whiteColor];
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.fullResImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.width);

}
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.fullResImage.image = nil;

}
-(void)configureWithObject:(PFObject*)object{


    [object[@"image"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError*error){
        if (!error) {

            /*THE PROBLEM IS HERE*/
            self.fullResImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            /*When i replace it by a local image [UIImage imageNamed:@"LARGE IMAGE ABOUT 1.2MB"] everything runs smoothly*/
        }else{
            [ParseErrorHandlingController handleParseError:error];
        }}];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using PFImageView instead of UIImageView.

```
if (object) {
     cell.image.file = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
     if ([cell.image.file isDataAvailable]) {
         [cell.image loadInBackground];
     }
}
```

When downloading images inside a cell, remember to cancel current download in prepareForReuse, otherwise you will see some duplicates when scrolling through fast.

I believe that PFImageView will handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks you that did the trick.
I wasn't using PFImageView because Xcode didn't recognise it. But when you suggested it i dug around and found that i have to include #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> . now everything is OK